# Drawing a circle: what to prefer for performance in OpenGL - Lines or a flat triangles?

Tags: c++, opengl

I know two ways of drawing a circle: circle that contains of GL_LINES or contains of flat triangles (GL_TRIANGLES). In the second case we need to store more vertices and display it every frame. But triangles better to use in tearms of performance of the GPU.

So what's better to use when you need to draw many circles on the screen? Lines or flat triangles?

Comment: Why don't you implement both and measure the FPS?

Comment: Depending on the size of the circle, it might be faster to just draw one quad (two tris) per circle, and use the fragment shader to make the circle (either with a texture or procedurally).

Comment: doing it procedurally in the fragment shader is almost certainly the fastest way. This way the geometry can just be as simple as a single rectangle, and only the pixels that are visible to the viewport will be processed.

Comment: Instanced quad with a simple texture will probably be even faster ;) And don't forget about [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

Comment: @user673679 can you tell me more about this approach? I can't imagine how to make a circle from a quad using fragment shader.

Comment: @JavaRunner You draw a quad covering the whole circle. In the fragment shader you calculate the distance of the pixel from the center of the circle. If it's approximately the same as the radius of the circle, color it! (You can use a smoothstep function to make it look nice and smooth too).

Comment: @user673679 can you provide me a little bit of code? I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that lines are being drawn with the help of triangles. You can check it by switching fill mode to wireframe.